# Folders not showing up in Windows HomeGroup

Tags: windows-7, homegroup

I have one desktop and two laptops connected to my HomeGroup. The problem I'm having is that the default folders show up just fine if I try and access files from one of the laptops, but I can't seem to get anything but the default folders to show up. Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On the folders other than the default folders, have you enabled them for sharing? That can usually be the issue as when you first set up Homegroup, it asks what you would like to share and it only shares those folders.